# Network Proxies all grayed out...why?

Tags: macos, networking, osx-snow-leopard

I'm a new Mac OS X 10.6 user, and I was trying to change the Network Proxies settings. However, it's all grayed out and was wondering how to make it editable? I'm the admin of the computer, so this is quite puzzling.

Answer (score 7):

Cancel out of the advanced/proxies settings and go to the network list. Click the lock icon at the bottom of the list & enter your password.

[image: lock icon]

When you re-enter advanced/proxies settings, they will be enabled.

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=471742#makechanges - same problem

Comment: Exactly for what I was looking for, saviour! :)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**
Restart your computer, lol. Man, this is so weird, only after I restarted my Mac that it allows me to edit it. Go figure.

Comment: just experienced the same problem.  Very puzzling.